# What's the best way to clean up a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a growing repository containing a dozen or so projects that I maintain using TortoiseSVN (as I am completely new to this and don't know the ins and outs yet). The space I have to hold the repository is limited so I want to back it up, then remove some of the older versions. For example, if a project is at version 50, I want to keep only 50,49,48.

Comment: No. Move the repository to a bigger space.

Comment: You really should read the "Version Control with Subversion" book (free as in beer) at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ to get a better understanding of the point of version control.

Answer (score 13):

Removing old revisions kind of defeats the point of version control, but you can just dump out the revisions you want to keep, then put them into a new repo, and delete the old one.

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r48:50 > svn.dump
svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < svn.dump
```

Or use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.1.3) to include/exclude the particular bits you want, etc. There also some info in the svn FAQs about [removal](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#removal) that you may find useful.

Comment: Isn't that only going to dump the specific *commits* from revisions 48 through 50? I think he's looking for the state of the repository as it was at revision 48, not just the commit there.

Comment: I just tried this. This doesn't do what I think the OP wants at all: it gets *only* the commits from those revisions. You don't get "the state of the repository at revision 48, followed by all commits necessary to get it to revision 50."

Comment: John: how are you running it? It works fine for me. It dumps fully the first revision specified, then the commits up to the last revision specified. Only if you specify the "--deltas" switch does it just dump the commits.

Answer (score 5):

**Can I delete older revisions or repositories to free up storage space?**

The short answer is no. The way Subversion and CVS work is that they keep an entire history of changes, including deleted files, binary files, etc. Each revision is dependent on the last revision, so you can't just chop out a revision somewhere in the middle or you corrupt your repository. There are 2 things you can do if you are running out of space: 1) Delete your module, and re-create it using just the HEAD revision, which will clear out all old revisions (but you will lose your commit history). 2) The better option- upgrade to a higher plan :-). This is less of an issue with Git since it has a much less server side storage requirement.

**How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?**

There are special cases where you might want to destroy all evidence of a file or commit. (Perhaps somebody accidentally committed a confidential document.) This isn't so easy, because Subversion is deliberately designed to never lose information. Revisions are immutable trees which build upon one another. Removing a revision from history would cause a domino effect, creating chaos in all subsequent revisions and possibly invalidating all working copies.

The project has plans, however, to someday implement an svnadmin obliterate command which would accomplish the task of permanently deleting information. (See issue 516.)

In the meantime, your only recourse is to svnadmin dump your repository, then pipe the dumpfile through svndumpfilter (excluding the bad path) into an svnadmin load command. See chapter 5 of the Subversion book for details about this.

quoted from:

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

http://codesion.com/benefits/faq.htm#deleterevisions

Answer (score 1):

**There's no way to "snip" a repository at a particular revision in the manner you describe.** What you could do is `svn export` the whole repository at the desired revision, then import it into a new repository, then replay the commits from the revisions after that from your log file into the new repository. This is not trivial.

Alternatively, if you just want to exclude some cluttered paths from your repository, and you have direct access to the file system where the repository is residing, you can use a combination of `svnadmin` and `svndumpfilter` to select the paths you want and prune all others.

Note that what you're describing is more or less against the point of Subversion: it's supposed to keep everything. If you frequently have trouble with this, consider establishing better checkin practices. Or consider using [**Git**](http://git-scm.com/), which makes this sort of experimentation virtually free.

Comment: Branches (svn copy) in subversion are almost free, both in time and space. And starting with subversion 1.6, merges of patches between branches use representation sharing to avoid duplication of data. I have no idea what you are referring to by saying "branches are space-expensive in svn".

Comment: In general, messing around with svn-dumpfilter is far more labor-intensive than messing around with git-filter-branch and/or .git/info/grafts. I've patched svn-dumpfilter heavily to support more kinds of history editing, and it's still not a nice tool.

Comment: @wcoenen: You are right. I didn't phrase that very well at all. @emk: Agreed, it's pretty awful. Nowadays I primarily use Git.

Comment: To be honest, I only use Subversion because I need to sync my code on various machines (home and work) and it is a nice way to do this via a USB stick. I find SVN a bit annoying though because it doesn't force checkouts and merging seems a bit dubious sometimes.

Comment: ... as in when I forget to commit on one machine and change code on another. For my simple requirements, SourceSafe-type functionality was great (but SS was not very stable).